# VSCode で Extension Pack for Java 拡張機能の使用時、色の情報を日本語で入力しても ?? と認識されてしまう

Tags: java, vscode, eclipse

VSCodeでExtension Pack for Javaの拡張機能を使用しています。色の情報「赤」を入力したら「red」を返すようにしたいのですが、「??」と認識され return "Unknow"; が返ってきます。

Eclipseなどの環境では正常に動作し、「赤」を入力したらちゃんと「red」を返してくれました。何がいけないんでしょうか？エンコードはUTF-8です。

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import Class.Translator;
public class KJava18 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("色名の入力してください");
        String input = Scanner.nextLine();
        String output = Translator.translateCOlor(input);
        System.out.println(output);

        Scanner.close();
    }
}
```

```java
package Class;

public class Translator {
    public static String translateCOlor(String color){
        if("赤".equals(color)){
            System.out.println(color);
            return "red";
        }else{
            System.out.println(color);
            return "Unknow";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: vscode での実行結果
色名の入力してください
赤
??
Unknow

Comment: 質問のタイトルは自己紹介をする場所ではなく、質問の概要を書くようにしてください。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました
JDKのバージョンを20から17のを使ったら正常に動きました。でも何が原因だったかわかりません。JDK20のエンコードが原因だったんでしょうか？